# ListView and ImageList Clearing not work?

Tags: c#, listview, directory, imagelist

I'm developing A program that uses the listView and ImageList to display Images from local folder.
The problem I have faced is: My code has `lstView_un.Items.Clear()`; method to clear the content of the list view before going to import any image. But it is appending the previous content to the newly or future loaded images. Even I have checked by clearing the listview with button and not clear any thing.

What is the problem? please help me to fix the problem!

the entire code is:

```
 lstView_un.Items.Clear();
                DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime d2 = dtp_unlist.Value;

                TimeSpan t = d1 - d2;
                double NrOfDays = t.TotalDays;


                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-NrOfDays);
                lstView_un.Items.Clear();
                string imagesPath = @"D:\Face Recognition System\UnknownFace";
                string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };
                var allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(imagesPath);
                List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
                foreach (string f in allfiles) files.Add(new FileInfo(f));
                var filesSorted = files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()))
                                       .Where(f => f.CreationTime < dt)
                                       .OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime);
                this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(256, 250);
                this.imageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
                foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in filesSorted)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.imageList1.Images.Add(fileInfo.Name,
                                                 Image.FromFile(fileInfo.FullName));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.FullName + "  is is not a valid image.");
                    }
                }
                this.lstView_un.View = View.LargeIcon;
                lstView_un.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
                lstView_un.Items.Clear();
                for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    item.ImageIndex = j;
                    item.Text = imageList1.Images.Keys[j].ToString();
                    this.lstView_un.Items.Add(item);
                }
```

Comment: What is getting appended, ListViewItems or Images?  Your code reloads the LV after it is cleared, so that seems intentional.  But the ImageList is used to populate the LV and the ImageList appears to be added to each time.

Comment: It seems like every time you clear it, you add new items. So, where's the problem?!

Comment: The images that are loaded previously are appended to the listView whenever I load images agin in to the listView. I don't know more about ImageList I think it will append, any way please help?

Comment: you are not removing the old images from the ImageList before adding more

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you clear `lstView_un` add the following 2 lines:

```
        lstView_un.SmallImageList.Images.Clear();
        lstView_un.LargeImageList.Images.Clear();
```

Because you clear the items, but you don't clear the images.